# Volley Mulipart get request

Tags: android, android-volley, response, multipart

I am trying to download some data from server using volley library. The data is very huge and hence want to download it in parts.
I am using get request.
Below is the code for my get request :

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // handle response
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { //handle error

        }) ;
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000, 0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
MyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);
```

How can I download the data in parts so as to remove the timeout error that I am getting?

Comment: does your downloaded content need an http request ?

Comment: Where do you get a timeout error?

Comment: Multipart get requests do not exist.

Comment: The possibility to download data iin parts depends on the server. So which API did they told you you could use?

Comment: I am using tastypie library of django